# Can NodeJS Crypto Handle Video Files?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, pipeline

I cannot get why the video files cannot be encrypted and then decrypted. When then I try to open the resulting file, it says "This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.". The same code works perfectly well with audio files. Here is the snippet:

```
// Nodejs encryption of buffers
const crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc',
    password = 'd6F3Efeq';

const fs = require('fs');

let r = fs.createReadStream('video.mp4');
let encrypt = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
let decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
let w = fs.createWriteStream('video.out4.mp4');

r.pipe(encrypt).pipe(decrypt).pipe(w);
```

Comment: When you compare the input and output files, what differences do you see?

Comment: Encryption and decryption process bytes and are independent of the file type. I have been able to successfully encrypt and decrypt an approx. 300 MB mp4 file with the posted NodeJS code.

Comment: Try using this one: https://gist.github.com/sayhicoelho/c574df8743b3c106f634213cdd1d4cae